# Generate static site from JSON array

Tags: middleman, static-site, hugo

I have a giant JSON array of every US state and city, along with other data about each of them. I'd like to iterate over the JSON and output a tree structure like this:

1. [Alabama]

   - index.html
   - [Abbeville]

     - index.html
   - [Adamsville]

     - index.html
2. [Alaska]

   - index.html
   - [Anchorage]

     - index.html
   - [Fairbanks]

     - index.html
3. ...etc

I'd have two layouts:

1. state.html
2. city.html

So far, I haven't found a great way to do this. A lot of static gens seem to have the ability to use JSON for meta data within content, but not for the primary source of content.

thanks!

Comment: Jekyll won't do this out of the box, but I have read about people who wrote custom plugins to do this sort of thing. This link had interesting info on how he did it: http://jimpravetz.com/blog/2011/12/generating-jekyll-pages-from-data/

Answer (score 2):

The Middleman static site generator supports this. You use their dynamic pages to create a list of the pages to create. The data comes from their data file feature. Here are the links to the pages explaining these

https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/dynamic_pages/
https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/data_files/

You would do something like have states.yml containing the state and city data

```
- states
    - name: Alabama
      cities:
        - name: Abbeville
          pop: X
        - name: Adamsville
          pop: Y
```

and then create the proxy pages e.g.

```
data.states.each do |state|
  proxy "/#{state.name}/index.html", "templates/state.html", :locals => {state: state}
  state.cities.each do |city|
    proxy "/#{state.name}/#{city.name}/index.html", "/templates/city.html", :locals => {state: state, city: city}
  end
end
```